# Make the control in LinearLayout not to fill all the space

Tags: android

I have a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fsfsdfds"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fdsfdsfds"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It fill the whole space of the activity.

How can I make these 2 `TextViews` and `EditTexts` take only space enough to show themselves (not fill all the space) and align the button to the bottom?

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout for this task.

Comment: What is the purpose of weights in this layout? and as Mr. Stein commented, RelativeLayout will probably be a better choice.

Comment: I think you should add a sketch of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I agree with @Udildan, It would be easier for us to help you of what you want to achieve if you add a sketch.

Comment: Then you should really learn about RelativeLayouts. It's worth the time spent on it. In short words, every View can be positioned `in relation` (on the top, on the right, on the bottom, ...) to the other Views or the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="TextView1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="TextView2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT :**

If you don't want to use the two LinerLayouts (and therefore gain even more performance), you can do the following :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/EditText1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/TextView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TextView1"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/EditText2"
        android:layout_below="@id/TextView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/EditText1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/TextView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TextView2"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if you do not use LinearLayout1 in code you can get rid of these containers and get more performance

Comment: @ligi I don't think it's a big performance deal + it looks more organized and less interdependent. Anyway, I added the other way (without the two containers)

Comment: @HicHr how much of an performance-impact it is depends on where it is used - but the deeper the layout the less performant. Great that you added the other way!

Answer (score 2):

Check This.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="fsfsdfds" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="fdsfdsfds" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

- You try with RelativeLayout, or else if wanted to be done with LinearLayout you need to consider weights if width is not fillparent.
- Check below sample to start with ..

  ```
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_weight="0.2"
      android:text="fsfsdfds" />

  <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_weight="0.8" />
  ```

  ```
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_weight="0.2"
      android:text="fdsfdsfds" />

  <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_weight="0.8" />
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Either convert to a relative-layout and use alignparentbottom for the button - or use layout weights for the linear-layouts

Comment: what convert? all of them? internal ones only? the external one? what?

Comment: depends a bit if you need to do something with the containers later on - but just for the layout one relativelayout with only the edittexts and textviews in them is enough